# How do you get leave a cell blank, if there is a string attached before it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

this might be a simple question, but I was just wondering how would you leave a cell blank if there was an error occurring and if there is a string attached in front of it.

So my code goes like:

```
="FW " & IFERROR(INDEX(Table[wx_week],MATCH(CONCAT($I$1,"-",A39),Table[L-Code],0)),"N/A")
```

The way I have it now is technically correct but for presentation issues it needs to just be a blank space. Mind you, I have other rows with "FW" so I can't just get rid of the "FW" portion.

Thanks

Comment: I'm slightly confused, why are you returning "N/A" from the IFERROR? What are the options: "FW text", or blank string?

Comment: just a blank cell. So I believe I have to change my formula somehow. The reason why I have "FW" in front of it, is because there are other rows that return values. This particular line though, when the data validation changes, sometimes there may be an error and if it is an error I want to leave it blank, because sometimes the value comes back, if that makes sense

Comment: `IFERROR("FW " & INDEX(Table[wx_week],MATCH(CONCAT($I$1,"-",A39),Table[L-Code],0)),"")`

Comment: Thanks BigBen! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The Same have been answered by @BigBen through comment and accepted by @Scott P

Here is the exact formula for the same.

```
=IFERROR("FW " & INDEX(Table[wx_week],MATCH(CONCAT($I$1,"-",A39),Table[L-Code],0)),"")
```